# Better approach to multiple database creates in codeigniter controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

What would be a better/cleaner approach to this function which creates multiple records across different database tables in a codeigniter controller :

```
private function newConcern($data) {
    $this->load->model('customer_model', 'customer');
    $this->load->model('complaints_dealers_model', 'dealer');
    $this->load->model('vehicle_model', 'vehicle');
    $this->load->model('complaints_vehicles_model', 'complaints_vehicles');
    $this->load->model('complaints_emails_model', 'emails');

    // create customer record
    $this->customer->create($data['customer']);

    // create concern record
    $this->create($data['concern']);

    // create dealer record
    $this->dealer->create($data['dealer']);

    // create vehicle record
    $this->vehicle->create($data['vehicle']);

    // create complaint vehicle record
    $this->complaints_vehicles->create($data['complaint_vehicle']);

    // check whether we have any email recipients
    if (!empty($data['department']) || !empty($data['recipients'])) {
        // process branch email
        $this->emails->processBranchEmail($data, $concern->id);
    }

    return true;
}
```

It feels like there's too much going on is this function, despite the necessity of all function calls.

Any suggestions for a better approach?

Comment: Should this logic be in the business model? Why does the controller need to know about or care about all the models that go into `a complaint`?

Comment: @RyanVincent Well perhaps it doesn't but what would be a better approach? If I'm sending data from the client side to the backend and need to create records in multiple tables, surely there needs to be a function which routes all of the create calls?

Comment: Do you have a 'business model' (or class), it will not be a `database object`  that will handle `a complaint`? It will take the input supplied by the controller and validate it and process it. It will then return the result and the data back to the controller for it to route wherever it wishes, normally to a `view`. what you call `model` are `database objects`. A 'business model' is the ''high-level' class that looks after `a compliant`.

Comment: @RyanVincent - so you're talking about a separate class specifically for `complaints` abstracted away from the controller and model?

Comment: Yes, this provides one place for business logic to be changed. i.e. If a new database model is required then this is the one place where it is used. The controller does not need to know about the new database table. If new input is required then the controller and view need to be changed. Where that new input is stored is not the concern of the controller or the view. It is decided by the `business model` and the `database models`. Think of who `needs to know' about certain information and who is allowed to change it.

Comment: Example: The controller formats the input and calls the appropriate routine on the `ProcessComplaint` class such as `makeComplaint($formattedInput)`. What gets returned is a `$response` that needs to be 'formatted' to display nicely to the user. That is the job of the `controller` and the `view`. The `ProcessComplaint` has used all those classes you mentioned to do the processing. Only the `business models` know about them.

Comment: @RyanVincent - This seems like a better approach, I'll try this implementation and see where it takes me. Thanks